# excel checkboxes in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007

I'm using VS 2010 c# with excel 2007.

The following code works with XP OS, but not with Windows7 64bit OS:

```
OLEObject ole = (OLEObject)excelWorksheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox1");     
((Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CheckBox)ole.Object).set_Value("true");
```

I'm using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.dll. I checked platform of this dll- it's anyCPU.
other code works fine.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working and how? Does it throw exception, or what?

Comment: When I try this code on windows7 64bit, I get "The type or namespace name 'CheckBox' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms'" which is odd, since intellisense will lead me straight to it.

Comment: Oh, hey. I only get that message in the immediate window; in the code it works just fine. Hunh.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenXml that you can find on Codeplex or using your NuGet package manager. It is a bit more comfortable tu use and gives you wider possibilities (in my opinion) than the excell interop class.